# How can I make my table fit the paper column, without decreasing the font size

Tags: tables, formatting, size

My table overflows to the right and does not fit the size of the columns. How can I make it fit the column, without decreasing the font size? I cannot decrease the size of the table since I am submitting a paper and they have regulations against decreasing the font size of the tables smaller to fit the page limits.

Here is a screenshot of what my table looks like when I run my code.
[image]

Here is the code I am using below:

```
\documentclass[sigconf]{acmart}

\usepackage{booktabs} % For formal tables
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\newcommand\vn[1]{\mathit{#1}} % or: \mathrm{#1}
\newcommand\Or{\mathrel{\big\Vert}}

\setcopyright{acmcopyright}


% DOI
\acmDOI{xx.xxx/xxx_x}

% ISBN
\acmISBN{978-1-4503-8104-8/21/03}

%Conference
\acmConference[SAC'21]{ACM SAC Conference}{March 22-March 26, 2021}{Gwangju, South Korea}
\acmYear{2021}
\copyrightyear{2021}

%\thispagestyle{plain} 

\acmArticle{4}
\acmPrice{15.00}


\pagestyle{plain}
\settopmatter{printfolios=true}
\begin{document}

\title{test}

\author{Anonymous Author(s)}





\begin{abstract}
abstract

\end{abstract}




\maketitle


{NoCallers/NoCallees}$=$0\\
 {LowCallers/LowCallees}$=$1\\
 1$<${LowCallers/LowCallees}$<=$5\\
 5$<${HighCallers/HighCallees}






\begin{table}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2.5pt}
\centering
    \caption{Quantifying the requirement-to-method rtm\textsubscript{m} Input Gold Standard}
    \label{GoldStandardInputCompleteness}
    \tabcolsep=2.5pt
    \begin{tabular}{|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|}
        \hline   \textbf{System}
        & \textbf{T\textsubscript{m}(\#)} & \textbf{N\textsubscript{m}(\#)} & 
        \textbf{U\textsubscript{m}(\#)}& 
        \textbf{Total} & \textbf{T\textsubscript{m}(\%)} & 
        \textbf{N\textsubscript{m}(\%)} & \textbf{U\textsubscript{m}(\%)}  \\ \hline
        \textbf{Chess} & 563 & 2389 & 3064 & \textbf{6016} & 9.36 & 39.71 & 50.93 \\ \hline
        \textbf{Gantt} & 343 & 23166 & 66725 & \textbf{90234} & 0.38 & 25.67 & 73.95 \\ 
        \hline
        \textbf{iTrust} & 307 & 7173 & 159562 & \textbf{167042} & 0.18 & 4.30 & 95.52 \\ 
        \hline
        \textbf{JHot.} & 439 & 12219 & 124262 & \textbf{136920} & 0.32 & 8.92 & 90.76 \\ 
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Probably you can save enough space by introducing linebreaks in the column headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your table fit by reducing the width of several of the columns.

```
% acmtableprob.tex  SE 562055

\documentclass[sigconf]{acmart}

\usepackage{booktabs} % For formal tables
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\newcommand\vn[1]{\mathit{#1}} % or: \mathrm{#1}
\newcommand\Or{\mathrel{\big\Vert}}

\setcopyright{acmcopyright}

% DOI
\acmDOI{xx.xxx/xxx_x}

% ISBN
\acmISBN{978-1-4503-8104-8/21/03}

%Conference
\acmConference[SAC'21]{ACM SAC Conference}{March 22-March 26, 2021}{Gwangju, South Korea}
\acmYear{2021}
\copyrightyear{2021}

%\thispagestyle{plain} 

\acmArticle{4}
\acmPrice{15.00}

\pagestyle{plain}
\settopmatter{printfolios=true}
\begin{document}

\title{test}

\author{Anonymous Author(s)}

\begin{abstract}
abstract

\end{abstract}

\maketitle

{NoCallers/NoCallees}$=$0\\
 {LowCallers/LowCallees}$=$1\\
 1$<${LowCallers/LowCallees}$<=$5\\
 5$<${HighCallers/HighCallees}

\begin{table}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2.5pt}
\centering
    \caption{Quantifying the requirement-to-method rtm\textsubscript{m} Input Gold Standard}
    \label{GoldStandardInputCompleteness}
    \tabcolsep=2.5pt
    \begin{tabular}{|r|p{2em}|p{3em}|p{3em}|r|p{2em}|p{2.5em}|p{2.5em}|}
        \hline   \textbf{System}
        & \textbf{T\textsubscript{m} (\#)} & \textbf{N\textsubscript{m} (\#)} & 
        \textbf{U\textsubscript{m} (\#)}& 
        \textbf{Total} & \textbf{T\textsubscript{m} (\%)} & 
        \textbf{N\textsubscript{m} (\%)} & \textbf{U\textsubscript{m} (\%)}  \\  \hline
        \textbf{Chess} & 563 & 2389 & 3064 & \textbf{6016} & 9.36 & 39.71 & 50.93 \\ \hline
        \textbf{Gantt} & 343 & 23166 & 66725 & \textbf{90234} & 0.38 & 25.67 & 73.95 \\ 
        \hline
        \textbf{iTrust} & 307 & 7173 & 159562 & \textbf{167042} & 0.18 & 4.30 & 95.52 \\ 
        \hline
        \textbf{JHot.} & 439 & 12219 & 124262 & \textbf{136920} & 0.32 & 8.92 & 90.76 \\ 
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

It fits but doesn't look all that good to me. If your are happy with it go for it, otherwise try tweaking the `tabular` column parameters and the row data.